# How to loop through all the rows in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through every row in column B and look for the string "NO" in each row.

The pseudo code is as follows :

Loop every row in column B

```
 If "NO" is in any row within column B

 Display and alert box "Unpaid"
```

End Loop

This code needs to be in VBA, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this will not be exactly what you want, but this is how you can loop over the rows in a column.  This will loop *every* row in the column. In Excel 2003 this is 65536 rows, and in 2007+ it is 1048576 rows, so it will be painfully slow to execute. You can of course modify it to work on only the used range in that column, if that is what you need.

Also, the `MsgBox` does not give you any opportunity to edit the sheet, nor does it give you any information about what cell(s) are affected. You will need to modify this code to do those actions, if needed.

```
Sub Test()
Dim col as Range: Set col = Range("B:B")
Dim r as Range

For each r in col.Rows
    If r = "NO" Then msgbox "Unpaid", vbInformation
Next

End Sub
```